# Geodataframe.explore() error: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'location'

Tags: python, dictionary, geopandas

I'm trying to plot an interactive map using Geopandas and its explore() method in Colab.

However, when I write:

```
my_geodataframe.explore()
```

The following error arises:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e71fb33b059f> in <module>()
----> 1 mapa_interactivo = mapa1.explore()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/geopandas/explore.py in _explore(df, column, cmap, color, m, tiles, attr, tooltip, popup, highlight, categorical, legend, scheme, k, vmin, vmax, width, height, categories, classification_kwds, control_scale, marker_type, marker_kwds, style_kwds, highlight_kwds, missing_kwds, tooltip_kwds, popup_kwds, legend_kwds, **kwargs)
    511             marker_kwds["radius"] = marker_kwds.get("radius", 2)
    512             marker_kwds["fill"] = marker_kwds.get("fill", True)
--> 513             marker = folium.CircleMarker(**marker_kwds)
    514         else:
    515             raise ValueError(

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'location'
```

I explicitly write the location:

```
my_geodataframe.explore(location=[40.463667, -3.74922])
```

But the error remains.

I'm creating maps which show the unemployment rate per province in Spain. The geodata can be downloaded from the following source:

http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/buscar.do?filtro.codFamilia=LILIM&filtro.codCA=11#

And the unemployment rate data per province may be downloaded from this one:

https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Datos.htm?t=3996

After merging the information into a unique geodataframe, I get something like this:

| Provincia | Codigo | Tasa_Paro | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| València/Valencia | 46 | 14.75 | MULTIPOLYGON (((-1.20715 40.00183, -1.21662 40... |
| Toledo | 45 | 16.77 | POLYGON ((-5.40611 39.87773, -5.40618 39.87884... |
| Teruel | 44 | 10.60 | POLYGON ((0.14136 40.71821, 0.12382 40.72081, ... |
| Tarragona | 43 | 15.51 | MULTIPOLYGON (((0.70759 40.63522, 0.70732 40.6... |
| Soria | 42 | 9.73 | POLYGON ((-1.99369 41.57709, -1.99311 41.57646... |

I've been able to plot a static choropleth  map with no problem:

[image: Unemployment rate per province. Spain. 2021T1]

You can find the code I've used to plot it in the following link:

https://github.com/AlejandroDGR/Proyecto_Difusion_Universitarios_INE/blob/master/Casos_de_uso_Python/C%C3%B3mo%20dibujar%20mapas%20est%C3%A1ticos%20en%20Python.ipynb

The problem, as stated above, comes with trying to plot an interactive map.

Any recommendations?

Comment: `required positional argument` the "positional" is there for a reason. just remove the `location=` part. The `location=` makes this argument keyword argument not positional one.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand your answer well, but if I write `my_geodataframe.explore([40.463667, -3.74922])` the following error arises: `ValueError: The GeoDataFrame and given column have different number of rows.`

Comment: I can't simulate it... two questions: 1.what version of geopandas and folium?  2. any strange geometry in your geodataframe.  Can you update question with data?  `my_geodataframe.head(5).explore()` does it fail?   if it does provide data from that

Comment: @RobRaymond answering your questions: 1. The geopandas version is 0.10.2, and the folium version is 0.8.3; 2. using `my_geodataframe.head(5).explore()` arises the same error. Then I'll edit the question with the data

Comment: You need to update folium to a recent version. GeoPandas does not support such an old version as 0.8.3

Comment: Please always provide the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors - they're full of information about what's going wrong and where. Thanks!

Comment: @martinfleis you were absolutely right. This was the problem. After updating the folium version, it works! Thanks a lot

Comment: AlejandroDGR - if @martinfleis doesn't post the answer, you can feel free to do so and accept your own answer so others know how to solve in the future.

Comment: I just posted the same thing as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is correct. The issue is that you are using the old, unsupported version of folium. GeoPandas `explore` has been designed to work with folium 0.12 and newer, you need to update.

Comment: This was the correct answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The first positional argument to [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html) is `column`:

> **column: *str, np.array, pd.Series (default None)***
> The name of the dataframe column, numpy.array, or pandas.Series to be plotted. If numpy.array or pandas.Series are used then it must have same length as dataframe.

If you're plotting a dataframe with more than one column, be sure to provide the name of the column you would like to explore, as in:

```py
my_geodataframe.explore('Tasa_Paro')
```

Comment: As I've stated above, the problem was the folium version as pointed by @martinfleis. However, what you suggest is correct too: this is the first part to create a choropleth map.

Comment: Got it - glad you figured it out!